# Folders In SiteMap Using Liftweb

Tags: scala, lift

I am wondering if it is possible to create folders in the webapp folder to rearrange my html pages. 
For now I don't know how to configure my siteMap in Boot.scala. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just specify the path like `"folder" / "template"`.  Here's an example from my `Boot.scala`:

```
Menu.i("showUser") / "user" / "show"
```

This will use the template in `webapp/user/show.html`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot. 
One more question, is it possible to make it transparent? That is to say when I access the page I type "localhost:8080/show.html" instead of "localhost:8080/user/show.html". To use it only to organize my files in fact

Comment: You can checkout [URL rewriting](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/URL_Rewriting), but that will probably only go halfway (I don't think it would change the generated HTML from the Menu snippet). Overall, though, you're probably better off keeping your site organization and HTML organization similar.